# My video is not showing up on my website, any advice?

Tags: html

After adding a video on loop successfully once on my website, I cannot add another video. The second video I tried adding did not show up on my site, instead it looks like there was an area for the video but no video was there.
My code is below:

```
  <video width=1000 height="571.4" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="images/Media2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the other video tag

Comment: Check your browser's dev tools

Answer (score -2):

Check if everything right with paths. I checked this with your code and it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <video width=1000 height="571.4" autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>

   <video width=1000 height="571.4" autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
</body>

</html>
```